# Black screen issue for Steam. How can I fix it?

Tags: steam

Steam just shows up as a black screen for me. I even managed to log into it but everything is just completely black and I can’t navigate through it. Any ideas?

Comment: See the answer to https://askubuntu.com/questions/1185938/playonlinux-steam-black-screen-update about changing the default GPU.